# Django, в чем различие записи ForeignKey

Tags: python, база-данных, django, orm

Django,  в чем различие  записи ForeignKey.
Делаю  inspectdb,  получаю:

```
class  Example(models.Model):
   contest_clan = models.ForeignKey(ContestClans, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
   lesson_folder = models.ForeignKey('LessonsFolders', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
```

В одном  месте нет ковычек ContestClans , а в другом есть 'LessonsFolders'. вопрос в чём разница ?

Comment: в случае c  `ContestClans` нужно определение модели `ContestClans`. В случае `'LessonsFolders'` определение модели не нужно, локация идет по имени таблицы, но это не orm-путь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) кратко:

- Для рекурсивной связи с собой же: `models.ForeignKey('self',
  on_delete=models.CASCADE)`.
- Для создания связи с моделью, которая еще не определена, но будет
  определена позже(ниже по коду).
- Ссылка на модель из другого приложения:
  `model.ForeignKey('app.mymodel', on_delete=models.CASCADE)`.